# Ruby on Rails - Does the scope of SessionsHelper reach models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Organisations module, I try to assign a value to a field before creating the Organisation record.

I use a before_create filter in the model, which usually works fine.
But when I try to assign a value coming from an attribute of the `current_user` method defined in the session, I get an Undefined method 'current_user' error message.

As doing this works fine in a controller, I wonder why it does not work in the model?

**Here is my code for the model:**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: organisations
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  playground_id          :integer
#  code                   :string(255)
#  name                   :string(255)
#  description            :text
#  parent_organisation_id :integer
#  organisation_level     :integer
#  hierarchy              :string(255)
#  created_by             :string(255)
#  updated_by             :string(255)
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null    
#

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base

### before filter
  before_create :set_code
  before_create :set_hierarchy

    validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :organisation_level, presence: true
    validates :created_by , presence: true
    validates :updated_by, presence: true
#   validates :owner_id, presence: true
#   validates :status_id, presence: true
    validates :playground_id, presence: true
#   belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"        # helps retrieving the owner name
#   belongs_to :status, :class_name => "Parameter", :foreign_key => "status_id" # helps retrieving the status name
        belongs_to :organisation
        has_many :organisations


### private functions definitions
  private

  ### before filters
    def set_code
      if Organisation.count > 0 
        self.code = self.organisation.code + '-' + code
      end
    end 

    def set_hierarchy
      if Organisation.count == 0 
        self.hierarchy = current_user.current_playground_id.to_s + '.001'
      else 
        last_one = Organisation.maximum("hierarchy")
        self.hierarchy = last_one.next
      end
    end

end
```

**Here is my code for the SessionsHelper** (inspired from Rails Tutorial)**:**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

end
```

Here is an example from a controller where the assignment works:

```
@business_flow.playground_id = current_user.current_playground_id
```

I'd be glad to understand why it does not work in the model.

Comment: `current_user` method is accessible from controllers (provided `SessionsHelper` is included in `ApplicationController`) and views (by default).

Comment: You do not have access inside the model to current_user. Give it as a parameter to the methods inside the model if there is no better way. usually there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SessionsHelper` module gets included into your controller class, so you can use its methods from there.  It does not get included in the model class.

In fact it probably wouldn't work even if you included it by hand, because the model would need access to the `cookies` method for the `current_user` method to work.  `cookies` comes from an `ActionController` method.

To achieve what you want, try making the change in your `Organisation` object from the controller that's creating that object, passing in the user information that the controller has access to.